# Let $(a_n)$ denote the number of ways to place parenthesis to multiply $n$ numbers $k_1,k_2\ldots k_n$. Find a recurrence relation for $ (a_n)$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Let $(a_n)$ denote the number of ways to place parenthesis to multiply $n$ numbers $k_1,k_2\ldots k_n$. Find a recurrence relation for $ (a_n)$

I can't think of way to go about this.

If we break the product $k_1\cdot k_2 \cdot k_3 \cdots k_n$ into groups of size $i$ and $n-i$ then it can be bracketed in $a_i \cdot a_{n-i}$ ways

so final answer should be $a_1a_{n-1} + a_2\cdot a_{n-2} + \ldots a_{n-1}\cdot a_1 $. Does this makes sense?

Comment: Look up "Catalan numbers". OEIS sequence [A000108](https://oeis.org/A000108)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

knowing all previous $a_k$, the choice you have is where to put the last multiplication. It can be anywhere  between $k_1$ and $k_n$ which correspond to $n-2$ possible location, let $i\in[1:n-1]$ be that position, then you have on the left $i$ elements and on the right $n-i$ elements, you know in how many ways you can put parenthesis on those, hence the result is :
\begin{align*}
a_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i a_{n-i}
\end{align*}

---

You can compute these numbers using generating function. The generating function is
\begin{align*}
xa(x) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} x^{n}\\
&=x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i a_{n-i}x^{n}\\
&=x+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i x^i \sum_{n=i+1}^{\infty}a_{n-i}x^{n-i}\\
&=x+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i x^i \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}\\
&=x+(xa(x))^2
\end{align*}
In other words
\begin{align*}
xa(x)^2-a(x) +1 = 0
\end{align*}
this is the generating function of the [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number), the end of the proof is similar to the wikipedia page and you obtain :
\begin{align*}
a_n= \frac{1}{n} {2(n-1)\choose n-1}
\end{align*}